# Uzo de komo antaŭ "ke" aŭ "ĉu"

Tags: punctuation

[ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/kom.html#kom.0o) klarigas, ke oni uzas *komon* i.a. *por apartigi suborditajn propoziciojn disde la ĉefpropozicio*. Jen ekz-oj:

*Mi vidis, ke li venas.* | *Li iris malgraŭ tio, ke ŝi ne deziris, ke li iru.*

*Mi ne scias, ĉu li venos.* | *Ne gravas, ĉu vi volas aŭ ne.*

Laŭ *Being Colloquial in Esperanto* ([11.8. Forms in T- + Ke/Ĉu](http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq110.html#sec11-8)):

> Except in the phrase **por ke** = “in order that,” it is conventional
>   to put a comma before **ke** or **ĉu**. I know of no reason for this,
>   although it is done in some European languages. The comma contributes
>   nothing to the sentence, and its use seems to be decreasing, but many
>   editors still regard it as an error or an Anglicism if you leave it
>   out.

Traduko: *Krom en la frazo **por ke**, estas konvencie meti komon antaŭ **ke** aŭ **ĉu**. Mi ne scias ajnan kialon pri tio, kvankam tiel oni faras en iuj eŭropaj lingvoj. La komo alportas nenion al la frazo, kaj ŝajnas ke ĝia uzo malkreskas, sed multaj redaktistoj ankoraŭ konsideras, ke ĝin preterlasi estas erara aŭ anglisma afero.*

Ŝajnas ke mankas regulo pri tia uzo de la komo. Pri kio temas? Ĉu la forlaso de komo en tiaj okazoj signifas ke oni uzas malbonan stilon? Aŭ ĉu vere temas pri malĝusta uzo de la (skriba) lingvo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ne estas devigaj reguloj pri la uzado de interpunkcio en Esperanto. Kp. la Lingvan Respondon de Zamenhof el "Esperantisto" (1893):

> La reguloj pri la uzado de la interpunkcioj estas en nia lingvo pli-malpli tiaj samaj, kiel en ĉiuj aliaj lingvoj; sekve ĉiu povas uzadi en Esperanto la interpunkciojn tiel, kiel li uzas ilin en sia nacia lingvo. Estas vere, ke en diversaj **detaloj** la uzado de la interpunkcioj estas malegala en diversaj lingvoj; sed ĉar la objekto ne estas tre grava, tial ni pensas, ke ne venis ankoraû la tempo por difini en nia lingvo severajn regulojn por tiuj ĉi detaloj.

La granda plimulto de la lingvoj eŭropaj, efektive preskaŭ ĉiuj ekster la angla, uzas komojn ĉirkaŭ subpropozicioj, do laŭ mi la aserto el *Being Colloquial in Esperanto* redonas sufiĉe idiosinkrazian, anglisman vidpunkton, precipe ĉar laŭ mia impreso ankaŭ en Esperanto, kiu daŭre ne ellaboris unuecan interpunkcion, la plimulto metas komojn ĉe ĉiuj subpropozicioj. Mi tamen ne konscias pri lingvistika studo pri la temo.

Do, sume: Faru interpunkcie, kion vi volas. Neniu aŭtoritato poste skoldos vin.

Comment: Estas trankvilige scii ke neniu persekutos min se mi iam fajfos pri tia komo ;-). Foje mi uzas ĝin, foje ne.

Comment: Ĉu estas vere ke preskaŭ ĉiuj eŭropaj lingvoj uzas komojn ĉirkaŭ subfrazoj? En la portugala, tiu komo ne estas uzata kaj kiam oni povas uzi ĝin (antaŭ “kiu”), ĝi draste ŝanĝas la signifon de la tuta frazo. Mi kutimas ne uzi tiun komon en Esperanto ĉar ofte mi metas rimarkojn inter komoj kaj tiuj apudaj uz-manieroj igus miajn frazojn tre kompleksaj.